# Flash input fields and embedding

Tags: flash

Is there any ways to use input fields without embedding the font to minimize `.swf` file weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can just use Arial or _sans or something similar. and don't embed the font, so flash will use the system font (if it's available).